# Fulltext-index in Neo4J in 2.0

Tags: full-text-search, neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to

- create a fulltext-index with a given lucene-analyzer on a certain node-Type (and certain fields only)
- to get this index updated automatically when a node of the given type is created / deleted
- query this index over the Cypher- oder the REST-API

I am using the Cypher/REST-Interface (and of course the shell, etc.) of the server not the embedded version.

If this is not available (which I guess): Is something like this on the roadmap?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Integrated fulltext index for labels is on the roadmap but not near term. 

You can still use the legacy (auto)indexes for automatic fulltext indexing. You would then have to filter the label after the index lookup in `START n=node:node_auto_index("name:a*") where n:Label return n`. See for the legacy auto-indexes: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/indexing.html and http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html

Comment: Why not use something like ElasticSearch and create a separate index of all the nodes, like the guys at http://linkurio.us have done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no

Little bit longer answer:
You can write a KernelExtension adding a TransactionEventHandler that amends the fields to be fulltext indexed to a manual index (aka legacy index). 
The code should be wrapped into an unmanaged extension and deployed to the server.
There something similar implemented within https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-uuid.

The contents of the legacy index can be accessed using `start n=node:myindex('lucene query string')` in `Cypher`

Comment: Are there any plans to add fulltext schema indexes in the near future?